# How do I convert subroutines to an object/package in perl / perl5?

Tags: oop, perl

**main.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;
use ReadData;

my $read = ReadData->new();
my @name = $read->getNames();
$read->printNames(@name);
```

**ReadData.pm**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package ReadData;
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

#

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return($self);
}

sub getNames {
    # read in data
    my @data;
    print "\nName of first matrix? ";
    chomp($data[0] = <>);
    print "\nName of second matrix? ";
    chomp($data[1] = <>);
    return(@data);
}

sub printNames {
    my @name = @_;
    print "\nname1: " . $name[0];
    print "\nname2: " . $name[1];
}

1;
```

I have these subroutines in another version of the main program, and everything works fine there. I don't call the object, and the input names are reflected correctly in the output as seen bleow:

```
my @name = getNames();
printNames(@name);

sub getNames { same as above . . . }
sub printNames{ same as above . . . }
```

The code I have pasted at the very top technically WORKS, because it runs, and gives output, but the output is incorrect.

When I enter "A" as the first name, and "B" as the second name, this is what I get back:

```
>>> perl alt.pl

Name of first matrix? A

Name of second matrix? B

name1: ReadData=HASH(0x1d082f0)
name2: A
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? I've been reading like 50 perl tutorials online and I can't wrap my brain around what I'm supposed to be doing. My only other real programming experience is OOP in Java, and I don't follow this perl constructor stuff . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main thing you're missing is that when you call a method on an object:

```
$read->printNames(@name);
```

the object itself (`$read`) is passed into the method (`printNames`) as the first argument, before all the regular arguments. (In Java this happens implicitly — the object is just magically made available as `this` — but in Perl it's explicit — the object is `$_[0]`.) So, you can change `printNames` to this:

```
sub printNames {
    my $this = shift;
    my @name = @_;
    print "\nname1: " . $name[0];
    print "\nname2: " . $name[1];
}
```

(Of course, in Perl, as in Java, it's more usual for instance methods to have something to do with the object. Your `printNames` method is strange in that it never uses `$this` at all. But this should get you started.)

Comment: ah thank you! i knew there was something that i was missing . . .

it is weird that i am not using the object for anything, but this was just a bit of prototyping for me to test the creation / calling of a new object after exporting subroutines from my main script into  a new package/module.

i don't have any need to use / call that print method, it was basically just there to ensure that the package/object was working correctly and i didn't mess anything up :P

Comment: @user1947267: You're welcome! And -- understood. Figuring-stuff-out code is not always realistic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store the data within the object rather than copying it back and forth:

**alt.pl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use ReadData;

my $read = ReadData->new();
$read->getNames();
$read->printNames();
```

**ReadData.pm:**

```
package ReadData;
use strict;
use warnings;

#

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return($self);
}

sub getNames {
    my $self = shift;
    # read in data
    print "\nName of first matrix? ";
    chomp($self->{name1} = <>);
    print "\nName of second matrix? ";
    chomp($self->{name2} = <>);
    return;
}

sub printNames {
    my $self = shift;
    print "\nname1: " . $self->{name1};
    print "\nname2: " . $self->{name2};
}

1;
```